# Saving Form Information to File on server

Tags: php, forms

I need to save form input into a text file on the server. I have created a text file on the server "email.txt", and given it permissions of 777. However when the form is submitted it text file remains blank.

My html is as follows:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">

<input id="email-input" type="text" name="your-email" placeholder="you@yourmail.com" class="cform-text" size="65" title="your email">

<input id="optin-button" type="submit" value="Download The Report" class="cform-submit">

</form>
```

Php as follows:

```
<?PHP

$email = $_POST["email-input"];

$to = "you@youremail.com";
$subject = "New Email Address for Mailing List";
$headers = "From: $email\n";

$message = "A visitor to your site has sent the following email address to be added to your mailing list.\n

Email Address: $email";

$user = "$email";
$usersubject = "Thank You";
$userheaders = "From: you@youremailaddress.com\n";

$usermessage = "Thank you for subscribing to our mailing list.";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

mail($user,$usersubject,$usermessage,$userheaders);

$fh = fopen("email.txt", "a");
fwrite($fh, $email);
fclose($fh); 

header("Location: mysite.com");

?>
```

Please assist. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (email) input bears the `id` of `id="email-input"` yet it is "named" `name="your-email"` no match for your POST variable.

Change:

```
$email = $_POST["email-input"];
```

to:

```
$email = $_POST["your-email"];
```

You cannot rely on `id` but the `name` of the element and that is why your file is blank.

Having used error reporting would have signaled the error.

**N.B.:**

I suggest you change `fwrite($fh, $email);` to `fwrite($fh, $email . "\n");`, otherwise, you're going to have all your accumulated Email addresses on one continuous line.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Answer (score 0):

Use *file_put_contents(file,data,mode,context)* available in php.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_put_contents.asp

If you want to append the text to the one you already have in the file, use FILE_APPEND in mode, so it would look like this:

```
file_put_contents("email.txt",$email,FILE_APPEND);
```